# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found when building for Sony Smart Glass

Tags: java, android-studio-2.1, sony-smarteyeglass

I am trying to develop an app for Sony Smart Glass in Android Studio 2.1.2. I tried to add the Sony Smart Glass sample library functions. I am getting an error like that

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

My **settings.gradle**:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:mylib'
```

My **build.gradle**:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options
      common to all sub-projects/modules.



  buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
  }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best starting place to create a SmartEyeglass app is with one of the samples. They already have all of the necessary dependencies declared for you. As a basic example try starting with the "HelloWorld" sample. In the end though your settings.gradle file should include this:

```
includeFlat 'SmartExtensionAPI'
includeFlat 'SmartExtensionUtils'
includeFlat 'SmartEyeglassAPI'
```

And your build.gradle file should include this

```
compile project(':SmartEyeglassAPI')
compile project(':SmartExtensionAPI')
compile project(':SmartExtensionUtils')
```

Please let me know if that helps.